# Filter or Search using Pure JavaScript if there are Inner Tables

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to make a search function using pure javascript . I have a small code snippet to work on . But this does not work if we have inner tables in multiple tr. How we can achieve this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input type="text" size = "4" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        if (td) {
          txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;  
          if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why this script function is not working if my HTML is like below

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>USA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why do you put a `table` inside a `tr`?

Comment: There are lot of tables like that in the existing application. I cannot change those because there are lot f logics . So is there any way to make it with existing structure.

Comment: my bad , i meant inner table inside TD . Updated the question .

Comment: What isn't working exactly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the contents of each td to see if it contains a table and then recursively check that table to see if its contents should be shown or not. I've done it here with some of your code, but I'd break the functions up even further.

This code returns a boolean representation of whether the inner table is completely hidden or not to use as part of the logic to hide the rows that contain inner tables. If the inner tables are hidden but another element in the row is not, the inner table rows are shown again.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  filterTableRows(table, filter)

}

function filterTableRows(table, filter) {
  const rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  let hiddenRows = 0;

  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {

    let show = false;
    const columns = rows[rowIndex].getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns.length; columnIndex++) {

      const innerTables = columns[columnIndex].getElementsByTagName('table');

      if (innerTables.length) {
        for (let tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < innerTables.length; tableIndex++) {
          if ( ! filterTableRows(innerTables[tableIndex], filter)) {
            show = true;
          }
        }
      } else {
        let txtValue = columns[columnIndex].textContent || columns[columnIndex].innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          show = true;
        }

      }
    }

    if (show) {
      rows[rowIndex].style.display = "";
      for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns.length; columnIndex++) {
        const innerTables = columns[columnIndex].getElementsByTagName('table');
        if (innerTables.length) {
          for (let tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < innerTables.length; tableIndex++) {
            showTable(innerTables[tableIndex]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      rows[rowIndex].style.display = "none";
      hiddenRows++;
    }

  }


  return hiddenRows == rows.length;
}

function showTable(table) {
  const rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    rows[rowIndex].style.display = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="text" size="4" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Pierre Truffant</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>France</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To see the inner table filter working, search for `pie`. To see a fault in the filter as it is currently coded, search for `fr`. This might get you close enough to finish it up though.